# How to send a message based on event Google PubSub?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I need some help with PubSub...

I need to send a message to a topic every time someone accept cookies in my website. This message should contain the encodedURL that contains the services accepted.

I have this script:

```
const topicName = "myTopic";
const data = JSON.stringify({
  encodeConsentURL:""
});

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const { PubSub } = require("@google-cloud/pubsub");

// Creates a client; cache this for further use
const pubSubClient = new PubSub();

async function publishMessageWithCustomAttributes() {
  // Publishes the message as a string, e.g. "Hello, world!" or JSON.stringify(someObject)
  const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(data);

  // Add two custom attributes, origin and username, to the message
  const customAttributes = {};

  const messageId = await pubSubClient
    .topic(topicName)
    .publish(dataBuffer, customAttributes);
  console.log(`Message ${messageId} published.`);
  console.log(customAttributes);
}

publishMessageWithCustomAttributes().catch(console.error);
```

This code works, it sends the message, what I'm finding very hard to do is how to set everything right for running this code in my cookie script. In my cookie script I have a function that writes the cookie, in the same function I would like to send the message, is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit late, but I don't get it, if you already have a working cookie script and a working publish script, isn't it just about putting them together?
If you still need help I'll be happy to help you

Something like

```js
const runEverything = async () => {
  try {
    await checkCookiesThing()
    await publishMessage()

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```

Comment: hey, it's not late at all! Thank you for sharing your solution!